# UIButton action not get worked in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a view of `UIView` subclass and 2 buttons and `UITableview` inside the view. In design part, one button first, then `UITableView` and then second button. When I click the first button(that is the button above the tableview), It gets the button action. But when I click the second button that is the button below `UITableView` it do not get the button action. If i drag the second button to above the position of tableview it get the action. Please help me.!

Comment: probably this button may be hide behind tableview

Comment: no actually the button is in other position from the tableview

Comment: If you still cannot sort this out and want to get the button to work, you may try to create a subview to contain that button and bring it to front.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you have a UIView with `userInteractionEnabled = YES`, it gets all the touches, therefore, any UIView behind this view wont get touched.

You can use a solution with `- hitTest:withEvent:`:

You need to subClass your UITableView, pass it a pointer to you 'behind' UIButton, and override `- hitTest:withEvent:` in your CustomTableView, like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL isInsideButton = CGRectContainsPoint(self.behindButton.frame, point);
    return isInsideButton ? nil : [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: actually my tableview did not override the button. for more clarification i just write down the positions. ButtonA (0,0,30,30) UITableView(0,30,150,150) and next button ButtonB(0,180,30,30) that is these 3 are in 3 location. When i click the ButtonB it not get the call. If i drag this one to location(50,0,30,30) it got the call. That is if i place the button next to the tableview(below) it just act like a label. No changes when click on it.

Comment: please help if you got it

Comment: @hilaj Maybe there is some other view on top of ButtonB? Are you setting it in the storyboard or in the code? Are you using auto layout, maybe you have a conflict? You can post your code and some screenshots of your storyboard, it will shed more light..